# Filter sql request with WHERE and ORDER express js API

Tags: sql, api, express

I don't know why this syntax doesn't work, I just want to get back my data throw this little API;
when I delete the 'ORDER by points DESC', it works.

This is the code :

```
.get((req, res) => {
            if (req.query.max != undefined && req.query.max > 0){


                db.query('SELECT * FROM rank WHERE id_championship = ?', [req.params.id] 'ORDER by points DESC', (err, result) => {
                    if(err){
                        res.json(error(err.message))
                    }
                    else{
                        res.json(success(result.slice(0, req.query.max)))
                    }
                })
            }
```

Thanks for your help !

I have tried to do it like this but it still not working...

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM rank WHERE id_championship = " + req.params.id + "ORDER BY id DESC";

                db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
                    if(err){
                        res.json(error('Fail database connection'))
                    }
                    else{
                        res.json(success(result))
                    }
                })
```

Comment: you need to concatenate (a string & a parameter & a second string) but you are not doing that

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have doing it like this but it still doesn't work...

Comment: I am NOT suggesting the second method (which opens sql injection issues I think) - in the first method you have `ship = ?', [req.params.id] 'ORDER` there is NOTHING between` ]` and `'ORDER` - **how does that concatenate?** Also in SQL **you will need a space before the word order**

Comment: in the second query you miss a space before the `ORDER BY` : `...+ req.params.id + "ORDER BY id DESC";` should be `... + req.params.id + " ORDER BY id DESC";`